# How to capture Outlook Form Region as a image? VSTO Outlook Addin

Tags: c#, .net, screen-capture

I want to save a image of a completed Form in Outlook. I am using VSTO Outlook Addin. I am able to capture a full screen image, but I am having no luck with the form region by its self. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
       var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(this.Width,
                      this.Height,
                       System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        var grxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

        grxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                    0,
                    0,
                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                    CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);


        string outputFileName = @"C:\Users\63530\Desktop\image.png";
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                bmpScreenshot.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I capture any window content. I hope it helps you, but it is not clear what is `this` you want to capture. This code works even if the window is not in foreground.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

    public static Bitmap GetSnapshot(IntPtr hWnd) // capture a window by its handle
    {
        Int32 windowLeft;
        Int32 windowTop;
        Int32 windowWidth;
        Int32 windowHeight;
        if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero) return null;
        if (!GetWindowRect(hWnd, out windowLeft, out windowTop, out windowWidth, out windowHeight)) return null;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(windowWidth, windowHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();

        PrintWindow(hWnd, hdcBitmap, 0); // from user32.dll

        gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
        gfxBmp.Dispose();

        return bmp;
    }

    private static bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Int32 left, out Int32 top, out Int32 width, out Int32 height)
    {
        left = 0;
        top = 0;
        width = 0;
        height = 0;

        RECT rct = new RECT();
        if (!GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref rct)) return false; // from user32.dll

        left = rct.Left;
        top = rct.Top;
        width = rct.Right - rct.Left + 1;
        height = rct.Bottom - rct.Top + 1;
        return true;
    }

    public struct RECT
    {
        public Int32 Left;
        public Int32 Top;
        public Int32 Right;
        public Int32 Bottom;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to capture the outlook form alone. "this" in my code refers to the Outlook Form Region that I am currently in.

Comment: If you can get a handle to that region, you can use this.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: Sorry Janos for the late reply. I did not. However I found another way to handle it. Thanks Alot !